# Why most of my heroes were "Temporarily unavailable" in ranked play?

Tags: heroes-of-the-storm

Pretty much as the title states it. I headed after a long rbeak of hots into ranked play and in the draft, most of my heroes had been greyed out with the info "Temporarily unavailable".
How does it come? And what is the reason?

Comment: Are those heroes level 5 or higher?

Comment: @Troyen: As far I had been able to identify, nope. I was assuming this could be the case. But then thought why should they have written "Temporarily unavailable" instead of something like "Not yet lvl 5". Hadn't played since, but it might well be that all of them were not lvl 5. But the last time I played this requirement wasn't in place, so I'd expected something more informative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chances are those heroes were not level 5 or higher.

In the [March 29, 2016 patch](http://us.battle.net/heroes/en/blog/20063493#User_Interface) the ranked requirements were updated to require heroes be level 5. This was done to ensure players had some minimal level of experience with the hero.

> Updated Ranked Requirements:
>
> - Due to the addition of bans, Ranked play now requires that players have access to at least 14 Heroes who have reached **Level 5 or higher** in order to participate.

I'm not sure why the error message isn't more descriptive, but you can always leave them feedback in their forums and maybe they'll clarify it.